# Firebase sending notification even after changing app package name

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have one curious doubt.
I am using FCM in my android app. Lets say my app's package name is `com.example.example` and I have got the `google-service.json` file from FCM using `com.example.example` and I am getting token and notifications also working fine.
But now I will re factor package com.example.example to com.sample.sample every where in the code including `google-service.json` file and I am able to get token here also.
Now if I go to FCM project with package `com.example.example` and ping from there the notifications are coming to `com.sample.sample`
My doubt is it should not come right?
Please help me out with this.

This is my app level gradle with the package name registered with firbase :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pushnotification.fcmnotifier"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my copied project's gradle with package name refactored :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.fcmNotification.fcmNotification"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: did you create a new project for `com.sample.sample`

Comment: No. Thats what my question is about.I have not created any project in firebase after creating with com.example.example. And in android app i have refactored old package name with new one thats it.

Comment: you have to change package name in Firebase > settings

Comment: Can you show me your App Level `gradle` file

Comment: please can you post your `Gradle` file ?

Comment: Hi please check my updated question.

Comment: Form firebase settings you can't change the package name, and in same `google-service.json` you can file key name  `package`   and it's value is `com.pushnotification.fcmnotifier`  right ?

Comment: check my answer.....

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: inside app directory --> google-service.json

Comment: make change in downloaded file located in your PC and delete current json file in android project and past changed google-service.json file

Comment: By "*ping from the console*", do you mean that you're sending a message to the specific registration token or are you sending a ping towards a topic?

Comment: To specific registration token using new package name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing your **application id** in your app's build.gradle file you need to register a new app in firebase console with new id. 
Then download the `google-service.json` file for that application.

Manually changing application id in your json file will not work.

Also note that if you are only changing the package name i.e the name used in manifest file, **google will not recognize that**. Changing application id in build.gradle is required to have new application id.

For more information check this : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html

Comment: thanks for your response. But the thing is i have changed appId in build.gradle <app level> also. But still it is working fine. Thats where i have doubt. Even changing appId in gradle and google-service.json file it shouldn't work. But in my case its working!!

Comment: have you registered your app with new id in firebase console ?

Comment: No i have not registered with new Id.

Comment: thats the issue. just go to firebase console settings, add new android app, provide the details and when done, it will give you a new json file for that app, put that in your project.

Comment: this will now tell firebase that this is a new app

Comment: No thats not my question. It is working fine even after changing package name and not registering that new appID with the firebase. It should not work like that rite? My doubt is that how it is working?

Answer (score 1):

This what the firebase support replied for this question. Hope it helps.

Thanks for reaching out to Firebase support.

It seems that your case might be related to this SO thread. As I quote one of our engineers, "Note that Firebase does not use the actual package name from your Java code, but uses the applicationId from your app's build.gradle file: .....But if you refactor your code into a different package, the application id won't be updated. That explains why the app will continue to work after such a refactoring."

Let me know if you need further help.

Regards,
Richard

This is the final conclusion from firebase :

I've discussed this with our team and it turns out that FCM uses GMP App Id rather than by package name. This is the reason why notifications would still work even if you have refactored both applicationId and package name.  I would also recommend you to have different Firebase app for different versions of your Android app instead of using only one.

Regards,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this point but may be a **reason** behind this issue is

After you have been changed the `Package` name **or** refectored `Package` you should have to change `applicationId` form **app level gradle** file, after that update every `package_name = "com.sample.sample"`(new refectored `package` name) from `google-services.json` file

Hope this will helpful for you

Comment: Yes i know it shouldn't be changed. But i have changed just for curiosity and it's working. According to firebase it shouldn't work but it's working.

Comment: yup may be you are right in your point but that's may be of this given reason just try to do change of all  `package_name` to new package name form your current `google-services.json` file

Comment: so we can find the exact reason behind this issue

Comment: You can not refactor package name from google-service.json.

Comment: what @Kiran i am not taking about from Firebase web site setting

Comment: i am talking about `google-services.json` located @ your app directory in android project

Comment: that you have downloaded it and import it in your project @Kiran ahaha

Comment: Ya thats what i am telling. Rename option is disabled in google-services.json file.

Comment: @Kiran you can't able to rename it ? from where you will try to renaming ?

Comment: @Kiran done ? any effect after changed `package_name` ?